# Algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I'm proving that $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{F}_{p^i}$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is a prime. I think I've gotten down how to prove that $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ is a field and that it is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

I have some difficulties with proving that $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ is algebraically closed.

My attempt is as following:

Suppose $f$ is a non-constant polynomial in $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p [X]$. If $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ contains a root of $f$, then it is algebraiclly closed. Per definition there must exist a $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ for a certain positive integer $k$ that contains all the coefficients of $f$. Take a root $\alpha$ of $f$ and consider the extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}(\alpha)$. How is this now a field of the form $\mathbb{F}_{p^l}$ for a certain positive integer $l$?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}(\alpha)$ is still a finite field...

Comment: So you can write it as a similar union but finite?

Comment: No, @SamoGrecco, but the extension $\mathbb F_{p^k}(\alpha)$ is a finite extension of a finite field, therefore a finite field itself, and, as it is of characteristic $p$, it must be isomorphic to exactly one of $\mathbb F_{p^l}$.

Comment: See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1873807/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3030335/11619). Nothing very detailed, I'm afraid.

Comment: There is also [this cute related, but different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1949145/11619).

Comment: And, finally, I found [a duplicate of my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/824137/11619). Deleting the version below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a polynomial $p(x) \in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p [x]$. Then, $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{p^k}[x]$ for some $k$. The splitting field is a finite extension of characteristic $p$, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^l}$ for some $l$ (by characterisation of finite fields). Hence, $p(x)$ must split over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$.